# filter objects from array that have the same value at given key

Tags: javascript, filter

Let's say we have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'A'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name:'A'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'C'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'B'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'B'
    }
]
```

I want to keep only this objects that have the same value at 'name' key. So the output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'A'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name:'A'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'B'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'B'
    }
]
```

I wanted to use lodash but I don't see any method for this case.

Comment: so, you want to keep object whose 'name' value exist in more than one object, right?

Comment: Could you clarify that? You only want to keep objects whose `name` exists at least twice in the array? Or that are grouped in pairs of two subsequent objects with the same `name`?

Comment: I only want to keep objects whose name exists at least twice in the array

Comment: @sympi Ah, okay, in this case, Rajesh’s answer should be the solution, though it doesn’t use lodash.

Comment: Is it important in which order the list every element comes? What happens if id:1 (name: 'A)' is id:5 instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea:

- Loop over the data and create a list of names with their count.
- Loop over data again and filter out any object that has count < 2

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'C' }, { id: 3, name: 'B' }, { id: 4, name: 'B' }];

var countList = data.reduce(function(p, c){
  p[c.name] = (p[c.name] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

var result = data.filter(function(obj){
  return countList[obj.name] > 1;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: To be honest, I did check your answer(*more than once*), and as always, its something that still goes over my head. Will read it few more times. ;-) Also will try to do it in 1 loop. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: it works with empty arrays and if it is later valid, then it gets an element with update. `concat` filters empty elements.

Answer (score 5):

A **lodash** approach that may (or may not) be easier to follow the steps of:

```js
const originalArray = [{ id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'C' }, { id: 3, name: 'B' }, { id: 4, name: 'B' }];

const newArray =
      _(originalArray)
       .groupBy('name') // when names are the same => same group.  this gets us an array of groups (arrays)
        .filter(group => group.length == 2) // keep only the groups with two items in them
        .flatten() // flatten array of arrays down to just one array
        .value();
        
console.log(newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

A shorter solution with array.filter and array.some:

```
var data = [ { ... }, ... ];  // Your array
var newData = data.filter((elt, eltIndex) => data.some((sameNameElt, sameNameEltIndex) => sameNameElt.name === elt.name && sameNameEltIndex !== eltIndex));
console.log("new table: ", newTable);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but the small size (long line) doesn't exactly help readability. The lambda with the `some` call could maybe be extracted to a named function?

Comment: Yes, named function can be used for these callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hash table and a single loop for mapping the objects or just an empty array, then concat the result with an empty array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 0, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'C' }, { id: 3, name: 'B' }, { id: 4, name: 'B' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], data.map(function (o, i) {
        if (hash[o.name]) {
            hash[o.name].update && hash[o.name].temp.push(hash[o.name].object);
            hash[o.name].update = false;
            return o;
        }
        hash[o.name] = { object: o, temp: [], update: true };
        return hash[o.name].temp;
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```