# Automatically click a link if anchor text contains keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a pure Javascript implementation.

On page load, I want to automatically click the link if a keyword is part of the anchor text.

```
<a href="#"> The Dog Barks </a>
<a href="#"> The Duck Quacks </a>
<a href="#"> The Bird Chirps </a>
```

I want to automatically click the link with the word duck.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write code to accomplish this yourself yet? Please post what you've tried

Comment: This should be fairly easy. Can you please post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get text, and then call the `String.includes` to check if the keyword present.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(this.text);
    });
  });

  function matchKeywordsAgainstLinkText(keyword) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(node) {
      if (node.text.trim().includes(keyword)) {
        node.click()
      }
    });
  }

  matchKeywordsAgainstLinkText('Duck');
});
```

```html
<a href="#"> The Dog Barks </a>
<a href="#"> The Duck Quacks </a>
<a href="#"> The Bird Chirps </a>
```

Links of methods I used:

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):  a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from): method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like objects, which is in this case return value of `document.querySelectorAll('a')`.

Using `forEach` loop we iterate all matching elements, and get the text of each matched anchor link, and compare if the keyword is present as a substring in the text. If matched, we do call [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) to simulate a mouse click event.

To do a case insensitive search use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```js
function matchKeywordsAgainstLinkText(keyword) {
  var regex = new RegExp(keyword, 'i')
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(node) {
    if (regex.test(node.text.trim())) {
      node.click()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT spoon-feed. Let OP share effort

Comment: @Rajesh May be the OP just started, and some code helps the OP to see how they works together. We generally help in SO sometimes, without seeing if the OP had put any effort or not, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998540/filter-objects-from-array-that-have-the-same-value-at-given-key/45998597#45998597).

Comment: In that case, instead of giving them answer, pepper them with reference links of individual parts. That way, they'll learn more For instance, *look for: **1.** How to search elements of specific type. **2.** How to loop over elements. **3.** How to check if element contains text. **4.** How to trigger specific events.* As an optional reference, we can even add reference to make search part case insensitive.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes you are right. And that all things can't be put together in a comment, so I went with an answer.. and I will add links now with comments.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thank you so much for this. I learned a few other things from your code sample.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thank you also for taking a stance for me and my question. If you could send me your Paypal I would love to give you a small bounty to buy yourself a coffee.

Comment: @joejam Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) my paypal.. thanks :)